# Print alternating elements of a string array

Tags: java, arrays

```
package com.javaprograms;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class PracticeJava
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] array = {"ABC","XYZ","PQR","STW"};

        //int num = array.length;

        for(int i=0;i<=array.length-1;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print alternating elements of a string array. For example, `{"ABC", "PQR"}` or `{"XYZ", "STW"}`. The code above doesn't work.

Comment: Well, you need to ask yourself the following questions:  1) What does the Arrays.asList() method do?  2) what is the for loop doing?

Comment: Instead of converting arrays to list, try to access an element in the array using square brackets like array[i]. Also, in the loop, you can increase I by 2 so it will skip one element each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not loop into the entire array and just get the odd or even element then print it? e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
   if (i % 2 == 0) // all even or "if (i % 2 != 0)" all odd
      System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase your loop variable with 2 in each loop:

To print all **even** elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 2) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
// Will print "ABC", "PQR"
```

To print all **odd** elements:

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i = i + 2) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
// Will print "XYZ", "STW"
```